# Rebus.ServiceProvider AddRebus overloads missing

Tags: rebus

I am trying to follow the documentation on GitHub for Rebus.ServiceProvider AddRebus method as documented in the link https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.ServiceProvider but it seems likely that there is something wrong with me as as I can't get it working as expected.

services.AddRebus(isPrimaryBus: false, ...); Missing

onCreated: async bus => {...}//Missing and

builder.Host.AddRebusService(
services => (...)
); also Missing

What other Nugets in addition to Rebus.RabbitMQ and Rebus.ServiceProvider are required to make it work properly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be in version 8 that is not final yet.

Comment: Exactly  but this SO post was a nice reminder, so I've published a proper Rebus.ServiceProvider 8.0.0 , which is available on NuGet.org now! 